# PowerShell read Excel cells in a array and create xml doument?

Tags: arrays, xml, excel, powershell

I use an array reading Excel content which should be used to create an xml file, but have troubles to allocate the array values to the write xml statements. 
Code of the array:

```
 # Parse Excel columns A and B and store it in array "$headerInit"   
 for ($j=1; $j -le $rowMax-1; $j++)
 {
    $Obj =  New-Object Psobject -Property @{
        Value = $ws.Cells.Item($j,2).text
        Header = $ws.Cells.Item($j,1).text
        No = $j
    }

    $DataArray.add($obj) # Visualize the array content
 }

    $DataArray | Out-Gridview
```

Example of the array content:

```
No   Header   Value
...
12   Address   1234,0x3030
...
```

Here the code excerpt to create the xml document (values "**1234**" and "**0x3030**" are insert manually, but should be allocated from the array $DataArray):

```
...
# Write node <address1>
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('address1')
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('address','1234')
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # <-- Closing the node <address1>

# Write node <address2>
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('address2')
$xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('address','0x3030')
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # <-- Closing the node <address2>
...
```

How can I allocate the 2 values, divided by comma "1234,0x3030" from the array $DataArray, Header "Address" in the create xml statement? Any help is appreciated - Thanks.

Comment: You've looked into using `.Split(',')` right?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I'm a newbie in Powershell and don't know how to store the left- and the right value in seperate variables?

Comment: How are you looping through `$DataArray`? You've not included the code that actually builds your XML it's hard to guess how you are referencing it's values.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I have solved the issue seperating the 2 values devided by comma.
Solution is:

```
$a,$b = $DataArray[12].Value.split(',')
```

Is there any easy way to alocate the values direct to the write xml statement without additional variables?

Answer (score 0):

As you've found from my suggestion, you can use `Split` to separate the two values you want:

```
$addressLeft,$addressRight = $DataArray[12].Value.Split(',')
```

You can also reference the seperate parts of the split directly, as `Split` creates an array you can use the index number to access each element:

```
$DataArray[12].Value.split(',')[0]
$DataArray[12].Value.split(',')[1]
```

The other option is to split the value into two propertys when you build `$DataArray`:

```
$Obj =  New-Object Psobject -Property @{
    Value = $ws.Cells.Item($j,2).text
    addressLeft = $ws.Cells.Item($j,2).text.Split(',')[0]
    addressRight = $ws.Cells.Item($j,2).text.Split(',')[1]
    Header = $ws.Cells.Item($j,1).text
    No = $j
}
```

I've left the original `Value` property in, but you could remove it if you only want the split values.